# Is it okay to change the status of an order in magento through a SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, magento

I am new to Magento. I have a website running on Magento where I need to change the status of almost 1000 orders from 'product_shipped' to 'delivered'. So is it a good idea to change the status of an order through a SQL query(using the order_id)? If it is, then what are all the database tables that are involved in changing the order status? Is it limited to just these two tables - 'sales_flat_order' and 'sales_flat_order_grid' ?

Comment: Isn't there a Magento way to do this? That sounds safer, and more resilient as new Magento versions are released. Do the status changes on a cron or in a background worker, if you are worried about the speed.

Comment: yes, I can always use the admin panel to change the status. But the number of orders are so big that i can't sit and change for every single order @halfer. Please help me if there is a workaround.

Comment: No, I mean there should be a defined programmatic API to do what you want to do, ideally for a set of orders, but if not, then for orders individually. I am advocating _against_ using raw SQL for the reasons I've already outlined - you may leave the database in an undefined/intermediate state.